# What is the indicated device under the tail of this B-29?

Tags: feature-identification, b-29

Was lucky enough to have the B-29 "Doc" flying over the house this weekend.

What's the mechanism under the tail indicated by the red arrow? Tail-strike preventer?

I did some searching and found it in other pictures, but never a labeled diagram.

[image]

- (Personal photograph)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Its a "tail bumper":

[image]
<sup>Source: [Fiddlersgreen.net](http://www.fiddlersgreen.net/models/aircraft/Boeing-B29.html)</sup>

Because the B-29 is so long, it helps prevent tail scrapes when taking off/landing.

Here is a close-up picture of the one on "FiFi":

[image]
<sup>Source: [Airport-data.com](https://www.airport-data.com/aircraft/photo/000862381.html)</sup>

Comment: Great pictures, thanks.

Comment: The OP might be interested to know that Concorde also had one, for the same reason.  [Details of Concorde's landing gear.](http://www.concordesst.com/gear.html)

Comment: Tail skids/bumpers (albeit not nearly as prominent as the ones depicted here) are common on long-bodied airliners (everything from Dash 8-Q400s to B787-10s)

Comment: @Graham thanks! I'll be lost in that website for a while. Wow.

Comment: I believe the B-25 has a fixed one.

Comment: Huh. I would have assumed it was an antenna. TIL, I guess.

Comment: Is there a wheel or something that attaches? It looks to me just like it scrapes along the ground.

Comment: @BruceWayne that's correct, it's a skid, not a wheel. If you hit it, your take off technique needs work.

Comment: @RonBeyer aha! Thanks for that simple clarification. I am (obviously) not a pilot and thought since the planes were so long it typically skids just enough to need a "tail bumper" for the last touch before taking off. Now I get it - you never want to use it, but it's there just in case.